# Why is NP-hard not necessarily NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, np

A problem X is NP-hard if every problem in NP can be reduced to X. But every problem in NP has a polynomial time verification algorithm, so then does that not mean that I can also verify X in polynomial time because every NP problem is reducible to X? Can someone please explain or give an example.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an abstract definition of the concepts NP-hard and NP-complete. If $A,B$ are two decision problems, say that $A \leq B$ if there is a polytime reduction from $A$ to $B$, that is, if there exists a polytime function $f$ such that $x \in A$ iff $f(x) \in B$. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathsf{NP\text{-}hard} = \{ B : A \leq B \text{ for all } A \in \mathsf{NP} \}, \\
&\mathsf{NP\text{-}complete} = \mathsf{NP\text{-}hard} \cap \mathsf{NP}.
\end{align*}
$$

Here is a different example. Consider the universe of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, ordered under $A \leq B$ if $A \subseteq B$. Let $\mathsf{X}$ consist of all subsets of some fixed set $X$. Define $\mathsf{X\text{-}hard}$ and $\mathsf{X\text{-}complete}$ just as above. You can check that
$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathsf{X\text{-}hard} = \{ S : S \supseteq X \}, \\
&\mathsf{X\text{-}complete} = \{ X \}.
\end{align*}
$$
In a similar way, NP-hardness is a lower bound on the difficulty, whereas NP-completeness is both a lower bound and an upper bound. In contrast to the second example above, there are many NP-complete problems, all of them having the same level of difficulty (two problems $A,B$ have the same level of difficulty if $A \leq B \leq A$).

Finally, here is a concrete problem which is NP-hard but not NP-complete: the halting problem.

**The halting problem is NP-hard.** Let $A$ be any computable decision problem, say computed by a Turing machine $M$ which always halts. Let $M'$ be the Turing machine which simulates $M$, halts if $M$ accepts, and runs into an infinite loop if $M$ rejects. Define a polytime function $f$ by $f(x) = (\langle M' \rangle,x)$. Then $x \in A$ iff $M$ accepts $x$ iff $M'$ halts on $x$ iff $f(x) \in \mathsf{HALT}$.

**The halting problem is not in NP.** The halting problem is not computable, and in particular not in NP.

Answer (score 3):

> But every problem in NP has a polynomial time verification algorithm, so then does that not mean that I can also verify X in polynomial time because every NP problem is reducible to X?

No. If a problem $P$ is **polynomial-time** reducible to $X$, it means that a solution for $X$ can be used to solve problem $P$ (in no more time that is required to find the solution for $X$), and not necessarily that a solution for $P$ may be used to solve problem $X$ (unless $X$ is also polynomial-time reducible to $P$). Provided, clearly, that those problems require at least a polynomial-time algorithm to find their solution. In other words, $X$ is at least as hard as $P$, that is we have an upper bound of the hardness of $P$.

You need to think about the reduction as a mapping: whenever you have a solution for $X$, you also have a solution for $P$. A more accurate definition of what a reduction is can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)#Definition).

Comment: It's a bit misleading when you say that a solution for X can be used to solve problem P without further time, since (1) the reduction takes time, and (2) the reduction could blow up the instance (by a polynomial amount).

Answer (score 2):

An *NP-hard* problem can be beyond NP. The polynomial-time reduction from your X to any problem in NP does not necessarily have a polynomial-time inverse. If the inverse is harder, then the verification is harder.

An **NP-complete** problem, on the other hand, is one that is NP-hard and itself in NP. For these, of course, there exist polynomial time verifications.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain or give an example?

I'll give an example.

The [*Clique*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) [*Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem):

> A **clique** in an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is a subset $V' \subseteq V$ of vertices, each pair of which is connected by an edge in $E$. In other words, a clique is a complete subgraph of $G$. The **size** of a clique is the number of vertices it contains.
>
> The **clique optimization problem** is the problem of finding a clique of maximum size in a graph.
>
> The **clique decision problem** is simply whether or not a clique of size $k$ (given input) exists in the graph.

The clique *decision* problem is in **NP-complete**, although the clique *optimization* problem is in **NP-hard**.

We **can** reduce from the clique *decision* problem to the clique *optimization* problem in polynomial time. This is easier, we simply solve the optimization problem, then check that the size of the maximum clique is greater than or equal to $k$. This is because of a simple relation: any clique of size $n$ contains a clique of size $n-1$.

We **cannot** verify the clique *optimization* problem in polynomial time. If the optimization problem is given a certificate, we can verify that the certificate *is* a clique in polynomial time (similar to the decision problem), but we cannot verify that the certificate is a *maximum* clique in polynomial time. Thus it is only in **NP-hard**, not in **NP**.

Generally speaking, a lot of problems in **NP-hard** are optimization problems because it is difficult to verify that a certificate for the problem is in fact optimal.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually enough if *one* NP complete problem X can be reduced in polynomial time to a problem Y to make Y NP-hard. (Because every problem in NP can be reduced to any NP complete problem).

Most problems can be viewed as special cases of a harder problem. If problem A is a special case of a harder problem B, then there is a reduction from problem A to problem B that isn't just polynomial time, but zero time.

Think about the consequence of what you are saying: If Y had to be in NP, then it would be impossible to have an NP-complete problem that is a special case of a more general problem that is not in NP.